# How to have a cell auto-update with name initials with any change in row

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel sheet with Companies in a list and the cities they operate in. The excel file will be used bu multiple people to add and update with time. I would like to have a column in the sheet where cells update with the initials of the user updating the respective row.

I have a code which pulls the windows username and inserts it into the cell if cell in that row is changed. The issue is that usernames are not names but a combination of the location of the office, initials and employee number.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Row < 5 Then Exit Sub
Application.EnableEvents = False
    Cells(Target.Row, "AE").Value = Date
    Cells(Target.Row, "AF").Value = Environ("UserName")
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

The employee number looks something like: "CAMA000000" where CA is the location, MA is the initials and the last 6 digits are the employee number. I just need the initials.

Answer (score 0):

This?

`Cells(Target.Row, "AF").Value = mid(Environ("UserName"),3,2)`

If there are only ever 2 or 3 initials followed by numbers, try this:

```
If Environ("UserName") Like "[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]#*" Then
    Cells(Target.Row, "AF").Value = Mid(Environ("UserName"), 3, 2)
Else
    Cells(Target.Row, "AF").Value = Mid(Environ("UserName"), 3, 3)
End If
```

Comment: Yes!!! This works. But I just realized that some names might have 3 initials. The first 2 letters will always be location but any letters after that will be initials and numbers after that for employee number.

Comment: Is it only ever 2 or 3 initials?

Comment: Yes, only 2 or 3